# Finding next neighbours in unsorted numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, sorting

Let's say I have a (2,N) numpy array looking like this:

```
a=[[ 0 58  0 72  0 90  0  0 15  0 33 43]
   [11  0 62  0 82  0 48  6  0 21  0  0]]
```

Is there an easy (and efficient) method of finding the index number of each entry's successor and predecessor in its **own** line and also in the **other** line?

If my question is confusing, here is an example what I mean:

Consider the entry a[1,6]=48 in the lower line.
Its (value) successor in its own line is obviously a[1,9]=21 and its predecessor is a[1,2]=62

Same goes for the upper line: Still regarding a[1,6]=48, I'd like to know what the indices of the successor and predecessor values in the **other** line are, which would be a[0,11]=43 and a[0,1]=58.

How do I quickly get these indices [1,9], [1,2], [0,11] and [0,1] by means of efficient numpy operations, without the need of programming everthing into a (slow!) Python loop?

Comment: If you sort each row, then you can find the next larger value (n+1) and use `index` to find the location of that value in the original array.

Answer (score 0):

Subtract the entry value from each array element.  For example, this will give you a second line of

```
[-37 -48 14 -48 34 -48  0 -42 -48 -27 -48 -48]
```

Filter for positive values and find the `min`;
Filter for negative values and find the `max`.
Repeat with the other row.

You can look up how to find the position of a min/max element.
[This question](/questions/9891561/filter-an-array-in-python3-numpy-and-return-indices) may help.

Comment: That looks smart and promising! Thank you :)